# Can't match expected type

Tags: haskell

On the call of  `coordenadas = criaCoordenada(num_col, width, height)` I'm getting the error for the 3 variables:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Float'
> In the expression: num_col
> In the first argument of `criaCoordenada', namely
>   `(num_col, width, height)'
> ```

```
type Point = (Float,Float)
type Rect = (Point,Float,Float)

writeRect :: (String,Rect) -> String
writeRect (style,((x,y),w,h)) = 
  printf "<rect x='%.3f' y='%.3f' width='%.2f' height='%.2f' style='%s' />\n" x y w h style


writeRects :: Float -> Float -> [(String,Rect)] -> String 
writeRects w h rs =  
  printf "<svg width='%.3f' height='%.2f' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\n" w h 
      ++ (concatMap writeRect rs) ++ "</svg>"

criaPosicoes :: (Integer, Integer) -> [Float]
criaPosicoes (num_col, x) = [fromIntegral x | x <-[0,x..(x*num_col)] ]


criaCoordenada :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> [Point]
criaCoordenada (col, w, h) = 
   let 
      lx = criaPosicoes (col, w)
      ly = criaPosicoes (col, h)
   in
      [(x,y) | y <- ly, x <- lx]



main :: IO ()
main = do
   let
      (num_lin, num_col) = (5, 5) -- Número de linha / coluna do retângulo maior.
      (width, height) = ( 41,19 )   -- Width / Height do retângulo colorido.
      (w, h) = ( (width * num_col), (height * num_col) ) -- Width / Height do SVG.
      coordenadas = criaCoordenada(num_col, width, height) --Error here


      style = "fill:hsl(20, 20%, 30%);stroke:rgb(156,156,139)"
      rects = [ (style, ((  0, 0), width, height))
              , (style, (( 41, 0), width, height))
              , (style, (( 82, 0), width, height))
              , (style, ((123, 0), width, height))
              , (style, ((164, 0), width, height))
              ]

      writeFile "colors.svg" $ writeRects w h rects
```

I know what the error means but I have no idea why...

Comment: From what I can see you aren't even using `coordenadas`, but it seems as if Haskell has inferred that `num_col` should be a `Float` rather than an `Integer`.  Try doing `(num_lin, num_col)  = (5, 5) :: (Integer, Integer)` and seeing if it gives you a new error.

Comment: @bheklilr Yes, now when I try to use `num_col` it says I can't use it because it was expecting `Float` and it's an `Integer` ... o.o

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro If I assume `type Point = (Float, Float)` and just set `writeRects = undefined` since you haven't given the type for it this code compiles just fine without me adding any type signatures.  I will point out that you have a slight indentation error in your `main` function, the `writeFile` function should be indented less so it doesn't fall under the `let` bindings.

Comment: Just updated with full code guys.

Comment: You are using `width`/`height` inside a `Rect` (`writeRects ...`), and that requires `Float`s. But you also use them as `Integer`s.

Comment: You need to figure out whether you want `num_col`, `width`, etc to be `Integer` or `Float`. `criaCoordenada` requires them to be `Integer`s, `writeRects` requires them to be `Float`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler inferred `w` and `h` to be `Float` because `writeRects` says they are. So also `width`, `num_col` and `height` are inferred to be `Float` because of `(w, h) = ( (width * num_col), (height * num_col) )`. That results in a type conflict in `criaCoordenada(num_col, width, height)` because `Float`s are passed to `criaCoordenada` which says it expects `Integer`s.

Comment: omg e.e how may I fix that ? I mean, the compiler thinks its a float becuase of a math that I did... WoW. I removed `width` & `height` from the calculation and wrote true number value. The error still the same

Comment: Can you try `(w, h) = ( (width * num_col), (height * num_col) ) :: (Integer, Integer)` and `writeFile "colors.svg" $ writeRects (fromInteger w) (fromInteger h) rects`? My Haskell is a bit rusty...